# catch constants as type string

Tags: php, pdo, constants

I have a function that takes a constant as string and would like to know if it is possible to obtain the value of the constant referent.

**myFunction( "FETCH_ASSOC" )**
the argument is related to **PDO::FETCH_ASSOC**

is this possible?
I'm putting together a class to work with the database, thanks

Comment: why do you want to make this function take constant as a string? Why don't you want to pass constant itself?

Comment: no specific reason, just did not want to delegate more responsibilities. I opted to spend the kind ( **FETCH_ASSOC , FETCH_OBJ...** ) because it is a class to improve abstraction. If I pass the parameter **PDO::FETCH_OBJ**, I'm assuming the use of PDO... I'm open to other suggestions, thank you

Comment: that's good idea to improve abstraction. you can use your own class' constants and initialize them with PDO constants.

Comment: good to know I'm on the right track :) I thought I'd do as you said, but as yet this test I chose to reduce the code to facilitate ... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`constant`](http://php.net/constant) function.

Note that it has to be the full qualifier though. Like `constant("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC")`, not just `constant("FETCH_ASSOC")` (unless you want the constant named `FETCH_ASSOC` in the global namespace, not in the PDO class).

Comment: so simple and I had not thought of that ... thank you very much!